# org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to resolve class

Tags: seam, drools

I have this seam project that a colleague built.  I am trying to get it to build in Jboss dev Studio.  He uses ant and builds manually.  I got the project built in JBDS and deployed on the JBoss server.  When i try to run the app, when it is time for the rules to fire, I get this error

> Caused by: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to resolve class 'dne.nmst.ciscoconfig.model.ConfigParams_$$_javassist_seam_4'

The offending code is in the drools config file which includes 2 imports

```
package Config;

import dne.nmst.ciscoconfig.model.ConfigParams;
import dne.nmst.ciscoconfig.action.ConfigSelector;
```

Perhaps I need more detail here, I don't know what would be useful to post.  I'm not even sure I know how to ask the question other than how do I fix this.  Advice anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure the jar containing those imports is available at runtime, rather than just at compile time?